# Cant search users in LDAP with name containing *

Tags: c#, .net, search, active-directory, ldap

My problem is that i cant search for users when their name contains *. The search string i used is just *.

I have read in:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28VS.85%29.aspx

that if the * (asterisk) sign appears in the DN, i must escape the character with /2a.

In my code, i have this statement:

```
if(searchFilter.contains("*"))
searchFilter = searchFilter.replace("*","\2a");
```

The code above will generate an error that says: "Unrecognized escape sequence."
I tried using

```
searchFilter.replace("*","\x2a");
```

but then, it will just replace the * with another *.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a double back slash.  You must escape the '\' from C#.

```
searchFilter = searchFilter.replace("*","\\2a");
```

Comment: Hi Richard, I also tried that one but the resulting search filter now contains two "\" characters when there should only be one

Comment: How do you know that?  If you are looking in the debugger, it will always display as C# string, thus two backslashed.

Comment: It worked. Sorry i was in debug mode thats why there were 2 backslashes